# Node regex to match newline character but not newline between quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am using NodeJS to stream a csv file and need to process each line. I haven't found a node csv parser module that supports newline characters within double-quotes properly.

Thus I am using the [split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split) module and need a regular expression to split on which would find *only* the newline chars *not* within quotes.

Something like `/(\r?\n)/` finds newlines but how can I omit the newline within the double-quoted strings?

example input (note the newline within the second line):

```
1,2,3,"foo bar baz",4,5
2,2,3,"foo bar 
baz",4,5
3,2,3,"foo bar baz",4,5
```

```js
inputCsvStream.pipe(split(/regex-for-newline-not-in-quotes/)).on('data', (line) => {
  // do something with proper csv line
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `split`, you could use the [`CSV Parse`](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/examples/) package, with which you could write:

```
var parse = require('csv-parse');
//...
inputCsvStream.pipe(parse).on('data', (line) => {
  // do something with proper csv line
});
```

If you really want to stick with `split` for this purpose, you could use the feature where you include in the split results the part of the delimiter that is in a capture group:

```
inputCsvStream.pipe(split(/(.*?(?:"[^"]*"*.*?)*)\r?\n/)).on('data', (line) => {
  // ignore the empty lines between the "delimiters"
  if (!line.length) return;
  // do something with proper csv line
});
```

This will take the part between the outer parentheses (in the regex) and add it to the piped result. Obviously `split` *also* pipes the parts between the delimiters, which in this case are always empty strings. So these need to be explicitly eliminated after the splitting.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I did try `csv-parse`. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to correctly handle newline chars within double-quotes. It splits the line on them. Unless I am missing some setting or option.

Answer (score 0):

At least [`fast-csv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) supports this:

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');

csv.fromString(`\
1,2,3,"foo bar baz",4,5
2,2,3,"foo bar 
baz",4,5
3,2,3,"foo bar baz",4,5
`).on('data', (d) => {
  console.log(d);
});
```

Output:

```
[ '1', '2', '3', 'foo bar baz', '4', '5' ]
[ '2', '2', '3', 'foo bar \nbaz', '4', '5' ]
[ '3', '2', '3', 'foo bar baz', '4', '5' ]
```

Comment: I tried `fast-csv` but it was a good deal slower than the alternatives and it didn't seem to support actual new lines in the string (I know typing \n in the string works ok), at least in my tests.

Comment: The code in the example _contains_ an actual newline in the string. If you don't believe it, use `csv.fromPath('your-file.csv')` instead of `csv.fromString()`. I've gotten pretty decent results from it, parsing 40K records in less than half a second.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it again and I still have the same problem. Process the stream, pipe thru fast-csv, it still treats that as a new line.

Comment: Perhaps it is because I am piping...   input.pipe(fastCsv()).pipe(...)

Comment: Actually, it seems to be because fast-csv isn't preserving the double-quotes around the string.

Comment: @JakeSankey the quotes are meant as delimiter, not part of the record. Any quotes _within_ the record should be escaped.

Answer (score -1):

You could put a negative lookahead assertion at the end:

`(\r?\n)(?![^",]*")`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX8yY0/1)

Comment: This will not work well when the quoted string has a comma after an embedded newline.